# With Javascript, enforce using scientific notation to represent numbers in IE8

Tags: javascript

I found that when using IE8, the large number will NOT be represented in scientific notation (e.g., 5e25), but it will be with Firefox3.

Can I enfore using scientific notation representation for **large number** with IE8?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "enforce?" Do you mean "use?" Or are you showing large numbers to the user? Show some code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//You can roll your own if you only care about large numbers-

```
Number.prototype.minExponent=function(min){
  min= min|| 5.0e+10;// define your own large number
  if(this>min)return this.toExponential();
  return this;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, the toExponential method is supported in all modern browsers. The basic form is:

```
number = 12345678;
x = number.toExponential(7);
alert(x);
```

This should produce 1.2345678e+7.

Comment: Sorry! I original intension is to use scientific notation to represent LARHE number for IE8 as Firefox do. Your solution will do to whatever number.

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding what you mean. Posting some code would help us. From what I can see, either you're trying to ensure the number appears the same to users across both browsers, or you're trying to work with significant figures somehow. For the former, all you'd have to do is call the toExponential method before displaying a large number. This will standardize your output.